# How to order by 5, 501, 50101, 6, 601, 60101, etc?

Tags: mysql, order-by

I've got a list of ledger account numbers. These numbers go like this:

- 5 (main account, #5)
- 501 (sub account of main account 5, #01)
- 50101 (sub account of this account, #01)
- etc.

So if I have a list and want to order this by account number, then I'd like to create this order:

- 5
- 501
- 50101
- 50102
- 50103
- 6
- 601
- 60101
- 60102
- 60103

etc.

However, any ORDER BY will give me:

- 5
- 6
- 501
- 601

etc.

So what is the proper way of working with this kind of numbering? I imagine I can get another column for ordering, but I really prefer to use the account numbers as IDs that I use for ordering, as not to make things too complicated.

Comment: Well, you could consider storing this data separately. What are you gaining by munging them together? If you store them separately, you can always order by a sum of the parts.

Comment: What I gain is simplicity. I will be needing this account number very often, but only infrequently do I need to order the list. So storing this separately makes things more complicated for only one specific, uncommon use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert it to `CHAR`  first:

```
ORDER BY CAST( AccounNumber AS CHAR )
```

Comment: Superb, works like a charm! Never knew about this, thanks!